# multiple regex condition after certain character

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I would like to do regex that return boolean value if it matches. I want to extract characters *after* `@`. It could be a lot of character. For example I want to check if email using `banana` or `apple`
domain.
sample:

`df.head()`

```
EMAIL
data1@gmail.com
data2@yahoo.com 
data3@banana.com
data4@apple.com
apple@gmail.com
```

I tried this
`df["sus"] = df["email"].str.match(r'([^@]*banana|apple)')`
but it also catch *before* `@`

result I got

```
SUS
False
False
True
True
True
```

result I want

```
SUS
False
False
True
True
False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.str.contains` because `.str.match` only searches for a match at the start of a string (it is based on `re.match`). Also, `[^@]*` matches zero or more chars other than `@`, so it does not restrict matching `banana` or `apple` matching (these words may appear at the start, end, anywhere in the string) if you use your pattern.

You can use

```
df["sus"] = df["email"].str.contains(r'@(?:banana|apple)\b')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I0otBW/1)

*Details*:

- `@` - the `@` char
- `(?:banana|apple)` - a non-capturing group matching either `banana` or `apple`
- `\b` - word boundary

Comment: Hi, thank you for your respond, I've made some edit I hope it wont be ambiguous. I will try this out

Comment: @yuliansen Yes, it is OK, I used `banana` and `apple` in my answer, too.

Comment: Dear Wiktor, 
thank you, your regex is great but what if I would like it to match everything after @ like.`` test1@fruit.banana.com `` =  ``True` . since your regex you afford me only match ``banana`` exactly after @. Please kindly answer my question. Thank you

Comment: Then use `@(?:[^.\s]+\.)*(?:banana|apple)(?:\.[^\s.]+)*` or something like `@(?:.*\.)?(?:banana|apple)(?:\..*)?$`

Comment: Tested so well, Thank you so much